# Handling Date columns in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-timestamp

I am trying to get some data from a SQL table. After reading the date the output looks like this

```
ID      BEGIN_DT                END_DT                   PX_LAST
----------------------------------------------------------------
13442   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-31 00:00:00.000      1
```

The data type shown in the output is `DATE`.

Can you let me know how to remove the timestamp 00:00:00.000 from the output?

Comment: Which DBMS? Date functions are very specific. You could try `cast(begin_dt as date)`, but again, that is not universal.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using

Comment: What database? Where do you see that output? If the type is `date` it shouldn't have any time component. Are you sure you aren't mistaking whatever your client shows for an actual value? At least in SQL Server `date` has no time component. The same with any database that differentiates between `date` and `datetime` or `timestamp`. SQLite has no types, much less a date type, and dates are stored using ISO8601 in columns with the text "facet"

Comment: I am trying to see which DBMS I am using by the command 
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sql_implementation_info

But that gives me the error 
`table or view does not exist`

Comment: In that case, check out the different ways that [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) selects and displays the version based on DBMS. Try each method and compare your results. It's not all inclusive, but has many common systems.

Comment: I see that this is an oracle database

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, you can `trunc()` the timestamp or convert to char.

```
select 
  current_timestamp,
  trunc(current_timestamp) as trunc_dt, 
  to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as char_dt
from dual
```

| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | TRUNC_DT | CHAR_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24-AUG-23 18.49.48.795426 +01:00 | 24-AUG-23 | 2023-08-24 |